# Jenkins execute shell script with parameters on remote ssh

Tags: linux, jenkins, ssh, jenkins-pipeline

I am attempting to run a bash script on jenkins using variables from the pipeline script to pass as parameters...ex
var1 = 'x'
var2 = 'y'

sshCommand remote: remote, script ./bash ${var1} ${var2}

However I am getting errors "Unknown parameters found for class type" , "command is null or empty"

Comment: Do you have a file named `bash` in your remote working directory?

Comment: Yes, the file is located in my remote working directory